# What is the difference between esc_html and wp_filter_nohtml_kses?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, security, sanitization

What is the exact difference between `esc_html` and `wp_filter_nohtml_kses`. Everywhere I look says that both strip **all** the html, the only difference I can see is to do with exactly how they do this. Does `esc_html` encode the tags and does `wp_filter_nohtml_kses` strip them altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what you have been looking at, [`esc_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) does **not** strip all the HTML, it escapes it, meaning it encodes it into safe HTML entities that do not break HTML tags.

[`wp_filter_nohtml_kses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses) strips all the HTML.

When in doubt **always** consult the source code. It is accessible online.

`esc_attr` is short and sweet, uses [`_wp_specialchars`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L314), defined in [*wp-includes/formatting.php*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2398)

`wp_filter_nohtml_kses` is defined in [*wp-includes/kses.php*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/kses.php#L1280), and "*Strips all of the HTML in the content.*"

Comment: Thanks. I think it's hard enough to appreciate the differences between some of these validation functions. I mustn't have been paying enough attention to the distinction between 'escape' and 'strip'.